# ubuntu16.04でメニューバーが消えた

Tags: ubuntu

ubuntu16.04でアップデートしたところ、立ち上がってもメニューが表示されません。(GNOME)terminalやコンソールは起動させることができ、compizのリセットをしたり、DISPLAY=:の設定をしたり、ググって出てきたものを手当たり次第試しましたがうまくいきません。
ちなみに、compizconfig-settings-managerはapt install できませんでした。

> パッケージcompizconfig-settings-managerは使用できませんが、別のパッケージから参照されます。
>   これは、パッケージが欠落しているか、廃止されたか、または別のソースからのみ利用可能であることを意味しています。
>   しかし、以下のパッケージに書き換えます。
>   compiz-core

とでたので、

```
sudo apt install compiz-core
```

としたらインストールはできましたが、ccsmもできません。

他に解決方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: 「メニューが表示されない」だけなのか「何も表示されない(=GUIすら起動しない)」のかがタイトルと本文の書き方が微妙に異なっていて誤解を与えそうです。 / デスクトップ環境は何を使っているかわかりますか？(恐らくGNOME辺りだと思いますが) / `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`辺りにエラーが出ていないかを確認してみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。メニューが表示されません。GUIは起動します。
デスクトップ環境はGNOMEです。

Comment: エラーは
Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
と
Error loading keymap /var/lib/xkb/server-0.xkm
でした。

Comment: https://www.garunimo.com/program/linux/column-linux3.php
を参照していますが、/etc/X11の中にxorg.confがないのですがどのようにエラーを直せばよいでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get search nvidia
```

で適切なnvidiaのパッケージを見つけて
それを

```
sudo apt-get install (パッケージ名)
```

でインストールしてみてください